# How to use the NavigationController from a tabbed ViewController?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have made an application for iOS in Xamarin Studio, the app uses primarily a Tabbar Controller to navigate views, but also a NavigationController.

How would I make the navigationController work with the tabController?

I've created a [Github repository](https://github.com/jackbillstrom/26498705-stackoverflow-question) for those who want to help me solve the problem with the combination of total Tabs Controller and Navigation Controller.

See my advanced flowchart created in paint.

[image]

I wish that Xamarin Studio didn't crash so that I've could get some output on what I'm doing.

Comment: Please take the time to extract and post the relevant portions of the code in the body of your question.  Posting code to external sites and linking is discouraged.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to make? Please post some code, flowchart or something

Comment: @EmilElkjærNielsen Added a simple flowchart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was several issues with getting the navigation properly working.

The **Storyboard** did not have any **NavigationController**, so this hindered some of the navigation attempts being made as **Exceptions** where being thrown on this being **null**.

Other issues included the **Maps** not being initialized for the Karta button, requiring the **MapsServices.ProvideAPIKey** to be called in the **AppDelegate** **FinishedLaunching**

There was a couple **UITableViewSource** being used where the **NavigationController** was being passed down to these implementations.  I didn't like this approach, so adjusted so that the selected item would be raised via a custom event handler to the parent **Controller** for further processing, and navigation occuring from there, instead of in the **UITableViewSource** where it was originally attempted.  Those were also **null** anyway before any corrections.

There was also a couple issues where **UIViewController**'s were being initialized referencing a **NIB** instance, although the content of the view was generated from code causing some **Exceptions** as well.

The above changes solved the **Navigation** issues @Jack was experiencing, although there is still a fair amount of work for @Jack to progress with this to finish off his application, and the fixes applied focused only on the **Navigation** issues he was experiencing (apart from the maps fix).

Once your back online @Jack, let me know as hopefully this should cover things from a Navigation point as I tried this thoroughly and I will send over the project.  This is far from complete though, however you don't get **Navigation** related issues now.